# Swift: Why can't I use 'contains(: )"?

Tags: swift, swift2

Step 1:
I declared a protocol, named `ARDevice`:

```
protocol ARDevice {
    var deviceName:String{get}
}
```

Step 2:
Then I used it to extend `NSNetService`：

```
extension NSNetService:ARDevice{
    var deviceName:String{
       get{
           return self.name
       }
    }
}
```

Step 3: I created an array:

```
var deviceList = [ARDevice]()
```

Step 4: I want to use `contains(:)` in a call back method, but I can't:
[image]

How can I do that?
Am I have to implement any protocol?

Comment: I'm not sure if Swift and Objective-C arrays overlap here. Try `containsObject:` instead. See [the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 if !deviceList.contains(service) { }
```

can only be used if the elements of the `deviceList` array – in your
case `ARDevice` – conform to the `Equatable` protocol. In particular,
a `==` operator must be defined for them.

The easiest solution here is to use the "predicate-based" `contains()`
method:

```
if  !deviceList.contains ({ $0.deviceName == service.deviceName }) {
    deviceList.append(service)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But if I want to know if two variable are the same object, how can I do? "==" seems can't use to object.

Comment: @AurumHuang: For reference (class) types, the "identical operator" `===` is used to check if two references refer to the same object.

Comment: I tried "$0 === (service as ARDevice)" ,but Xcode throws an error: "Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'ARDevice' operands".Do I have to implement the Equatable protocol too, before I use '==='?

Comment: @AurumHuang: In order to use `===` with ARDevice you must declare the protocol as a "class protocol", see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038750/can-we-test-if-objects-conforming-to-the-same-protocol-are-identical-in-swift-wi.