# Swift Check if Two Objects Conforming to a Protocol Are Referentially The Same

Tags: swift, types

I have a protocol that forms the base of many classes—in the example below, `StaticFile` and `RemoteFile`. I have a reference to a variable that points to the protocol

```
protocol ContainerDelegate {}

protocol FileProtocol {
    var delegate: ContainerDelegate? { get set }
}

class StaticFile: NSObject, FileProtocol {
    var delegate: ContainerDelegate?
}
class RemoteFile: NSObject, FileProtocol {
    var delegate: ContainerDelegate?
}

class Container: NSObject, ContainerDelegate {
    var item: FileProtocol

    override init() {}

    func something() {
        if item.delegate !== self { // This fails
        }
    }
}
```

I don’t even care about types really, I only want to see if the delegate is not the current object (by reference). What’s the best way to make the failing line work correctly?

Comment: You should probably be using `!=`.

Comment: Could you please provide a full, running code sample?

Comment: Can’t use `!=`, my classes are stateful. And done—the above code will show an error.

Comment: If you want to compare by reference then @luk2302's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Similar issue: [Can we test if objects conforming to the same protocol are identical in swift without casting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038750/can-we-test-if-objects-conforming-to-the-same-protocol-are-identical-in-swift-wi/32038820#32038820).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to upcast the `delegate` and then check for equality:

```
func something() {
    if item.delegate as? Container !== self {
        print("hi")
    }
}
```

Full working code example

```
protocol ContainerDelegate {}
protocol FileProtocol {
    var delegate: ContainerDelegate? { get set }
}

class StaticFile: NSObject, FileProtocol {
    var delegate: ContainerDelegate?
}

class Container: NSObject, ContainerDelegate {
    var item: FileProtocol

    func something() {
        if item.delegate as? Container !== self {
            print("hi")
        }
    }

    override init() {
        item = StaticFile()
    }
}

let c = Container()
let c2 = Container()

c.item.delegate = c2
c.something() // hi gets printed

c.item.delegate = c
c.something() // hi does **not** get printed
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `ContainerDelegate` does not require that a conforming type be a reference type. You could write a `struct` that conforms to this protocol, and using `===` and `!==` for structs doesn't make sense. (The `===` and `!==` operators take `AnyObject?` parameters, and only class objects can be passed as AnyObject.)

One way of fixing this is to use `protocol ContainerDelegate: class {}`, which requires reference semantics, and would allow you to write `item.delegate !== self`.

Another way, as luk2302 points out, is that since you only care about whether the object is identical to `self`, you can first try casting it to the same type as `self`, before the comparison.

Comment: Actually, this answer also helped a lot! I just had a case where I couldn’t upcast, as I wanted to referentially compare two FileProtocols.

Comment: Another good thing about using `protocol X: class` is that it would allow you to use `weak var delegate: X?` which is usually what you want for a delegate object.